# IE Never finishes loading SharePoint page when JavaScript is disabled

Tags: 2007, internet-explorer, javascript

I am working on a solution that loads SharePoint pages in a copy of IE. When the page finishes loading an event is triggered that executes some code in the application that wraps IE.

Now this all works fine and well, until JavaScript is turned off in the browser, a requirement for this solution (Don't ask). Naturally I don't expect the out of the box SharePoint user interface to be fully functional without JavaScript enabled, but although the web page is rendered correctly IE's progress bar never finishes the loading process. As a result my code is never triggered.

Try it for yourself.

1. Open Internet Explorer.
2. Disable JavaScript access for the Internet zone.
3. Navigate to a public SharePoint site [such as this one](http://www.sharepointcommunity.com/Site%20Pages/VendorDirectory.aspx).
4. Watch in amazement how the progress bar never finishes.

Does anyone have any idea about what is going on or if there are any workarounds?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need JS.
Most sites need it nowadays:(

Comment: My questions is that I don't understand why the page, according to IE, never finishes loading. If js is disabled then I can understand certain functionality not working, but a file that is downloaded via HTTP should have nothing to do with this. A download is a download and when the last byte is in IE should see it as done and stop the progress bare and raise the relevant event.